# How to Scrape data hidden inside of a collapsible element?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping data from this [site](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/browse/?CIK=0001084869), where I wanted to extract a tags hyperlinks data from the collapsible content under **Selected Filings** section. From my code, I used *find_all()* [divs] with the [id] of *selected-filings-annualOrQuarterly*, to first select the div which they are found in.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/edgar/browse/?CIK=0001084869", headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
print(r.status_code) 
print(r.url)
for div_tag in soup.find_all('div', {"id" : "selected-filings-annualOrQuarterly"}):
    print(div_tag)
    for ul_tag in div_tag.find_all('ul'):
        print(i)
        for li_tag in ul_tag.find_all('li'):
            print(li_tag)
            for a_tag in li_tag.find_all('a', href=True):
                print(a_tag)
```

These are the results I get:

> 200
> https://www.sec.gov/edgar/browse/?CIK=0001084869 
> -<div id="selected-filings-annualOrQuarterly"-> 
> No 10-K/10-Q filings for this company in last 
> <span id="selected-filings-annualOrQuarterly-days-old"-><-/span-> days<-p>
> <-/p>
> <-/div>

Whenever, I run the above code, I just get [span] elements inside the [div - id] and nothing more.
What I really wanted is to obtain all the links (a tags) present in the specified [div] element, inside [li] [ul] elements. When I view the page source of the said website, everything is there. But the code returns NOT even the [ul] and the [li] tags inside the [div]. It's seems like they are hidden. This is the order and location of the a tag hyperlinks. id(specified above) > ul > li > a(links to be scraped)

Results I expected:

> <a href='ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/1084869/000143774921025463/flws20210926_10q.htm'-> 
> <a href='ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/1084869/000143774921025463/flws20210926_10q.htm'->

Depending on the number of links found, the number of links returned will vary. How can I be able to obtain the hyperlinks inside the said location?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to retrieve? For example, the urls for all 10-K filings of the company?

Comment: Yes @ Jack Fleeting. What I'm trying to retrieve is the links/urls of either of the 10-k, 10-Q or the 8-K that are recent. This code will be running on a daily basis and looking for information that is recent/updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I view the page source of the said website

the inspector is not the source, that's the modified page. the source is `ctrl+u` and you'll see that your data is not here.

the data you want is in a json that you can see in the network tab: https://data.sec.gov/submissions/CIK0001084869.json

i saw in the comments that you wanted `8-K` forms too, so i refactored things a bit to make the script more versatile.
i added a random cik to make some tests. all data is now in a dict

```
import requests
from collections import defaultdict
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

ciklist=['0001084869','0001856236']
search_forms=['10-Q', '10-K', '8-K', '8-K/A']

cik_data={}
for cik in ciklist:
    data=requests.get(f'https://data.sec.gov/submissions/CIK{cik}.json', headers=headers).json()
    base_url=f'https://sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/{cik[3:]}'
    cik_data[cik]=defaultdict(list)
    for i, form in enumerate(data['filings']['recent']['form']):
        if form in search_forms:
            fname=data['filings']['recent']['primaryDocument'][i]
            access_number=data['filings']['recent']['accessionNumber'][i]
            access_number=''.join(access_number.split('-'))
            cik_data[cik][form].append('/'.join([base_url, access_number, fname]))
```

Comment: Thanks for this @diggusbickus! I wish to know how to get the json for which these data and links reside. I also realized that links returned is only the last segment of the whole link. Like for instance, one of the links is [https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/1084869/000143774921025463/flws20210926_10q.htm], but what is returned is the segment after the last backslash flws20210926_10q.htm. Is there a way to return it especially from this position ix?doc=/...... (the first backslash)? Thanks

Comment: you're right, there was a trick. i think it's ok now

Comment: Thanks @diggusbickus, it's now working much better. I just want to know how I get the json of the page, as I have many other pages to work on.

Comment: it's just the cik number. your url was `https://www.sec.gov/edgar/browse/?CIK=0001084869` and the json is `https://data.sec.gov/submissions/CIK0001084869.json` ?

Comment: Thanks, I was looking to get data from other filings/pages too and seems I'll use the json.

Comment: yes if you have already a list of cik numbers you don't even need beautifulsoup

Comment: Great! Much thanks!

Comment: I'm scraping the web for those links, I will have the base link then I will just replace the CIK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238966/discussion-between-steel8-and-diggusbickus).